# Does the [chili] tag contain any scope that the [peppers] tag doesn't?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

All [chili](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chili)s are [peppers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peppers), but not all [peppers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peppers) are [chili](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chili)s. :) I don't see why the chili tag is necessary, because as I see it, the entire scope of that tag is covered by the peppers tag. I was going to suggest a synonym, but got a message:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> Reverse synonym chili already proposed on the tag chilli

Does that mean both [chili](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chili) and [chille](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chille) have to become synonyms of peppers? I don't think I can do that myself.

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that the "chili" tag (how'd you do that anyway) is useful in that some people, myself included, are only interested in chilis. As such it would be frustrating to have to filter through various sweet pepper posts just to find chili posts under a general "pepper" tag.